# Скачивание сайта посредством curl

Tags: curl, php

Как скачать сайт в виде html c картинками css и js скриптами? Чтобы потом его запихнуть в папку site с названием домена www.com.

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь программами типа Teleport Pro (windows) или WebHTTrack (linux)

Comment: Постойте? для чего я в пометках ставил curl php? От балды? Я четко и ясно сказал, что как организовать скачивание сайтов посредством curl php.

Comment: Совет более чем верный. Или вам такой банальный алгоритм непонятен?) Открываем курлом баш.орг, качаем главную, сохраняем в `www.com`, вытаскиваем из нее все ссылки, в т.ч. на скрипты, css, картинки и прочие аяксы, и далее "рекурсивненько" грузим все в `'www.com/'.$filepath`. Да, это долго и геморно, но довольно просто. А еще на третьем часу работы скрипта все же советую скачать телепорт про. 

Как вариант выпросить у хозяев фтп-доступ))

Comment: Хех) Ну я думаю вот первый вариант геморный мне подходит) Спс)